# Laravel 5 custom user Auth methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My authenticated user has a color assigned to them via a relationship in the User model.

I would like to go:

```
return Auth::color()->id;
```

To return the logged in users color id.

How do I go about doing this?

I also can't do:

```
Auth::user()->color()->id
```

or

```
Auth::user()->color->id
```

I am getting `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$id`

However all relationships are defined.

I am coming from Laravel 4, what am I doing wrong?

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function color() {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Colour');
    }

    public function salesarea() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Salesarea');
    }

    public function getNameAttribute() {
        return $this->first_name." ".$this->last_name;
    }

}
```

Comment: damn!!! you define your relation as `colors ` but when you calling this method you'r using 'Auth::user()->color()->id'. I have no idea how it will allow you to do that. Change the calling method according to init method.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Is there anyway to simply go Auth::color->id?

Comment: basically Auth interact with user and colour has relation with user. So Auth have path to interact with colour through user. So you need to come through auth->user()->color->id.

Comment: Can you show me you color model... so I can suggest you multiple solution to deal such requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing i cant create a comment yet i'll write my question here,

- Is this suposed to be a one to many or one to one ?
- Is the user_id column present in your color database table ?

if it is a one to many you need to check if:
your user model has this function

```
    public function colors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Color');
}
```

your Color model has this function

```
    public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

If so you should be able to do 
Auth::user()->colors witch is a collection of color objects

if it is supposed to be a one to one
you need to check if your user model has this function

```
public function color()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Color');
}
```

your color model has this function

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

If so you should be able to do 
Auth::user()->color witch is a color object

Comment: Yes, all relationships are set correctly, it is a one to one, see my user model in edit. I really don't understand how this can be going wrong :(

Comment: i see your function is called colors, but in your examples you use color, is this just a typo or did you check that ?

Comment: Typo sorry, also doing $user = \App\Models\User::find(1)->color->name; works as expected, so I dont know why access via auth doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If your user table has a `color_id` column, then you want a *belongs to* relation, not a *has one*. A has one relation is where the *other* table would have a `user_id` column (say a `profiles` table where a profile can only belong to one user). But in your case, I’m assuming a color could be assigned to *many* users, therefore a user belongs to a color, and a color has many users.

So in this case, you need to change your relationship:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function color()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Color::class);
    }
}
```

You will then be able to query the color from the authentication services:

```
$color = Auth::user()->color;
```

Also keep an eye on your model naming, as you used both the American and British English spellings of ‘color’ in your question.